# Application insights performance counters spam

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have two identical resource groups for dev and qa.
They have the same services and same configurations.

At some point, I found that appinsight in QA contains a lot of performance counters which are produced by the app service plan.

[image: qa logs]

[image: dev logs]

I've tried to compare their configuration, but they look similar.

[image: dev]
[image: qa]

What can cause such different behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72515686/application-insights-performance-counters-spam) it says,

> At the set sample interval, Azure Monitor gathers data from all deployed performance counters on all agents. For the time period defined by your log analytics workspace, the raw data is accessible in all log query views and has not been aggregated.

According to [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/azure-monitor-costs#estimating-performance-counter-ingestion) it says,

> Performance counters show how the system resources are performing. Performance counter data ingestion depends on your environment size and usage. In most cases, performance counters should make up 80 to 99% of your data ingestion for Azure Monitor for Azure Virtual Desktop.

***References:***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/performance-counters